# Learning vectors

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm learning how vectors work.
I have two vectors, one contains names and the other one contains "phone numbers". I wrote a function which is displaying all names and all phone number next to each other:

```
(define v4 (vector 'Tom 'Michael 'John 'Julia))
(define v5 (vector 2343 1343 2112 372637))

(define db (λ (n)
             (cond
               ((equal? (vector-length v4) n ) "stop" )
               (equal? 0 (display (vector-ref v4 n))
               (display " ")
               (display (vector-ref v5 n ))
               (displayln " ")
               (set! n (+ n 1))
               (db n)        
               ))))
(db 0)
```

**Result is:**

```
Tom 2343 
Michael 1343 
John 2112 
Julia 372637 
"stop"
```

Is this the right way to do it? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler way in Racket, using [iterations and comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) and [format strings](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._fprintf%29%29). Arguably, this is more idiomatic and easier to understand:

```
(define (db v1 v2)
  (for ([name  (in-vector v1)]
        [phone (in-vector v2)])
    (printf "~a ~a~n" name phone))
  "stop")
```

Even if we were to write an implementation using only explicit recursion and standard procedures, it's better to avoid using `set!` to increment the index, pass parameters instead - including the vectors that are going to be iterated, there's no need to refer to global definitions:

```
(define (db v1 v2)
  (let loop ((idx 0))
    (cond ((>= idx (vector-length v1)) "stop")
          (else
           (display (vector-ref v1 idx))
           (display " ")
           (display (vector-ref v2 idx))
           (newline)
           (loop (+ idx 1))))))
```

Either way and assuming that both vectors have the same length, it works as expected:

```
(define v1 (vector 'Tom 'Michael 'John 'Julia))
(define v2 (vector 2343 1343 2112 372637))
(db v1 v2)

Tom 2343
Michael 1343
John 2112
Julia 372637
"stop"
```